# How to disable beep tone in xfce when the delete button is pressed?

Tags: arch-linux, audio, xfce, bell

I newly installed xfce on Arch Linux. xfce makes a beep noise every time I press the delete button or backspace, which is really annoying. How can I disable this?

I tried un-commenting `set bell-style none`, but that didn't work.

Comment: Did [you](http://superuser.com/questions/241187/how-do-i-reload-inputrc) [reload](http://superuser.com/questions/419670/how-do-i-reload-inputrc-using-a-bash-script) `~/.inputrc` after uncommenting `set bell-style none` (reload command: `bind -f ~/.inputrc`)? If yes, then try one of the [mentioned](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Disable_PC_speaker_beep) [methods](https://www.debian-administration.org/article/110/Removing_annoying_console_beeps). E.g. by unloading `pcspkr` module: `rmmod pcspkr` or by `xset b off`.

Comment: Might I recommend [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/152691/how-to-disable-beep-sound-in-linux-centos-7-command-line/152694#152694)?

Answer (score 37):

To disable the bell for all X applications:

```
xset b off
```

Comment: May be helpful: http://xfce.10915.n7.nabble.com/Beep-td8866.html

Comment: This works fine. Although after rebooting I have to redo it. Is there a way to permanently disable it?

Comment: @math You can add it to your `.xinitrc` file

Comment: If you are using a preinstalled XFCE instance you can add it in Session and Startup as well.

Answer (score 13):

Go to SETTINGS → SESSION → STARTUP, button ADD, type: name "beep" and in last field type "xset b off".

Comment: In Settings -> Session and Startup there is no "Startup" section. There is a Settings -> Session and Startup -> Application Autostart -> Add button... is that what you are referring to?

Answer (score 3):

This Arch Wiki page lists all the options to disable PC speaker (beep) very nicely: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PC_speaker

For instance, as mentioned by @SauceMcBoss, you can set:

```
xset -b
```

(or `xset b off`) to disable it in Xorg (which will solve your problem). To make the change permanent, add this line to either your `.xinitrc` or `xprofile` file.

Or, to disable the PC speaker globally within one session, the `pcspkr` kernel module can be unloaded with:

```
rmmod pcspkr
```

To prevent its loading by `udev` at boot, you can blacklist it in a `.conf` file in `/etc/modprobe.d/`. For instance:

```
echo "blacklist pcspkr" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Comment: A bit late to this party, but beware of running the last `echo` command if you have already blacklisted modules (i.e. you already have a `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` file). I'd suggest appending, with `echo "blacklist pcspkr" >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` or since you need to be root to edit that file, `echo "blacklist pcspkr" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`

Comment: Thanks @mrbolichi. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried every single thing in this article, and more, and none of them worked.  Sure some disabled the system beep for the terminal application, but all of the OS-related beeps were still on.
What finally worked?  Finding and renaming the dang sound file (and logging out and back in of my X session).
`/usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/bell.ogg`
I renamed the above to "bell2.ogg".

Now I can use my computer without wanting to flip my desk over.

Who the hell thought a super loud beep every time you pressed a key was a good idea?  It's like some sort of weird psychological torture.

Note, this will probably revert itself if the `ubuntu-sounds` package requires an upgrade, and you'll need to re-move the file off.

Comment: This also is the sound I am hearing, but I rather would like to know which component starts this and deactivate on the root. Do you haven an idea, where this is started?

Answer (score 0):

In XFCE, similar [to this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/452937/484783), you can disable the bell on XFCE login like this:

```
cat <<EOF > ~/.config/autostart/beep.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=0.9.4
Type=Application
Name=beep
Comment=
Exec=DISPLAY=:10 xset b off
OnlyShowIn=XFCE;
RunHook=0
StartupNotify=false
Terminal=false
Hidden=false
EOF
```

Tested on Debian 11 Bullseye with XFCE4. Also works over RDP connections using [FreeRDP](https://www.freerdp.com/) (the `DISPLAY=:10` env variable is set because of that, if you use the default X display, then you don't need it).

P.S. I really hope XFCE and other window manager maintainers come to their senses and introduce a sensible default, namely to disable this terrible system bell because it's such a nuissance and annoynace you wouldn't believe. It's extremely annoying and can literally scare small babies and even grownups.
Please get rid of this bell.